# Clean code - how to break a method that returns String

Tags: java, coding-style, clean-architecture

I have the following method (splitted because was too long):

```
private String replacePlaceholders(IncidentFullDTO incident, String text) {
        text = replacePlaceholdersPL(incident, text);
        text = replacePlaceholdersENG(incident, text);
        text = replaceAdministratorProcessor(incident, text);
        text = replaceRateSummary(incident, text);
        return text;
    }
```

Each method (like replacePlaceholdersPL) returns a new "text". All these methods are very similar. Example:

```
    private String replacePlaceholdersPL(AAA incident, String text) {
            if (text.equals(PlaceholdersEnum.CURRENT_DATE.getPlaceholder())) {
                text = text.replace(PlaceholdersEnum.CURRENT_DATE.getPlaceholder(), getCurrentDate());
            } else if (...) {
                text = text.replace(PlaceholdersEnum.DATE_TIME_START_INCIDENT.getPlaceholder(), formatDate(incident.getIncidentDate()));
} else if(...) {}
} else if(...) {}...
```

How to write this code with clean code principles? I want to split this code to not to invoke unnecessarily all these methods like replacePlaceholdersENG when the previous method changed the "text" variable... I get the "text" variable from the docx file and I want to replace this text with the other text value

Comment: Sounds like a question for [codereview.se]. You'll need a more complete example though.

Comment: Ooo I didn't know about the Code Review website... Thanks a lot

Comment: from your code it seems you have different types of text, and without knowing what is its type it is hard to make it clean, you may need to create types for each group such as LanguageText, SummaryText  then you can apply your transformation without repeating yourself

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by clean code principles but you can create a class and set incident and text as instance variables. Each function call will have the updated text.

```
class PlaceHolder {

 Incident incident;
 String text;

 public PlaceHolder(Incident incident, String text){
   this.incident = incident;
   this.text = text;
 }

 public String getResult() {
   replaceA();
   replaceB();
   ....
   return this.text;
 }

 public void replaceA(){}
 ....
}
```

Comment: clean code: the must read for any developer https://www.amazon.de/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882